# Going back to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I have a pavilion g7 pc by hp. Like so many others, I jumped on the chance to upload windows 8 only because of all the hype.  What a fool I am. I hate Windows 8 with a passion.  It is extremely difficult to navigate, screens pop up all over the place, can't shut down unless you navigate to lower left or upper right to find settings.I want like so many others to go back to Windows 7.  I can't determine where to go to find out if I have recovery disks on this computer.  I can't find anything anymore. Like the advise from an old friend said: "If its not broken, don't try to fix it"  I should have listened.   HELP PLEASE!

Comment: The best way would be to insert a Windows 7 installation disk and choose to format the parition that Windows 8 is installed on.  All of the problems you point out, can be resolved by, using keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: +1 for hating on Win8 :) If it's not broken HIT IT HARDER!

Comment: I think the best way to try out a new OS, is to run it in virtual box, then you don't disrupt what you already have.

Comment: You use the same method with the CD as you would for any OS... format the drive and install Windows, you can't roll back the OS.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming windows 7 came installed on the machine, Hp has a recovery partition that restores the computer to its factory settings.

As long as you didnt wipe that partition when you installed windows 8, All you have to do is start up the computer and hit f11 repeatedly until the hp recovery program starts.

Then simply follow on-screen instructions

Answer (score 0):

As MalwareManiac stated, using the recovery partition is probably the best way to go.  If that has been wiped out (or otherwise not working) you can download an ISO image of the appropriate Windows 7 disc you need here: http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/

Make sure that the one you pick matches the version that came pre-installed on your PC (Home Premium or Pro) or the install key that came with your PC won't work (it should be on a sticker somewhere on the PC).  From the ISO file, you can either burn a DVD or use it to create a [USB install disk](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool).  I would recommend the USB option, as it runs much faster than a physical disc.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop originally came with Windows 7 then you can do so by backing up all your important files, then boot from your Windows 7 disk, format the drive (erasing Windows 8 and everything else), and then proceed to install Windows 7 like normal. Once done, copy back all your important files and re-install your software.

But MalwareManiac's solution sounds the best option if there is a recovery partition already available.